# Oracle apex mouse dynamic active

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

We have an application built in Oracle APEX 4.2.6 couple of years ago. We have found a problem with respect to session value. Here is the situation. In the first page, we created a "Interactive Report" with link on the column to open up another window with details for that particular record (or estimate in my case). The link target is set "target="_blank", which means it will open  up a new window. This interactive report lists all the estimates that a salesperson is working on. Ideally a salesperson will work on different estimate at a time, so that open up different windows to work with. To create the problem, I have created a sample app in https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1:106597525107750::::: with username as demouser and pwd as Reston12!

This will log you into the workspace and then run the app "Test DP"  (id 126218)

Once  you login, click on "List Estimate" on the left hand side, you will see two estimates on page 2. Click on the first estimate and it will open up a new tab (second tab). Look at the session value for P3_ESTIMATE which will be D17-12345 (as I clicked on that particular estimate).

Now the salesperson will go and click on second estimate and we will see another tab (third tab) and session value for P3_ESTIMATE will be D17-98765.

Now the salesperson has two windows open. He will now jump to the second window where estimate D17-12345 is opened and will click on Update Button. Since the session value for P3_ESTIMATE is set to latest click which is D17-98765, the PL/SQL Code (Process) on submit will update the wrong estimate at the database level. (Look at the PLSQL code when submit).

How do I create a dynamic action which will read the value of the P3_ESTIMATE from that particular page and do the appropriate updates?

Thanks
Ajay

Comment: What is the workspace name for sample app?

Comment: Workspace name is SIRC

Comment: This seems like bad design.  The salesperson probably doesn't want to have multiple windows open at once, it would be easy to get confused and make a mistake.  A better way to manage this would be to make the link open in a modal window rather than a new page.  This would force the salesperson to deal with one estimate before moving on to another.

Comment: You might consider upgrading to APEX 5.1 wherein you can use the APEX_CLONE_SESSION request which will create independent sessions in each window. http://joelkallman.blogspot.com.au/2016/07/apex-session-isolation-across-multiple.html